# Is $f(x)=-|\sin x|$ a convex function?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Recently my assistant in calculus told us that $ f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = - |\sin x |$ is a convex function. I hope this is not true. Maybe he made a mistake but he was trying to give us an example of a function that is convex (not strongly) and that have infinite number of roots. I mean, that function is convex on periods but surely it isn't on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It isn't convex.

Comment: wow that speed.

Comment: A convex function can't have more than two roots.

Comment: Are u sure ? Strongly convex can't , but I believe convex can . Imagine a line on x-axis and the rest of function grows as $x\to +- \infty$

Comment: The closest to being correct that your assistant is, is that at those points where $f''(x)$ exists, we have $f''(x)>0$. While this is a sufficient(!) convexitiy criterion for twice differentiable functions, it says nothing about non-differentiable functions (such as this)

Comment: A not necessarily strictly convex function can have infinitely many roots.

Comment: @sranthrop but not isolated

Comment: So Yves is wrong ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A function is convex if it is always on the top of any secant line.

But $-|\sin x|$ is not so. consider a line between any two peak.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to show that it isn't convex. You can take the points $\Big(\dfrac{\pi}{2},-1\Big),\ \Big(\dfrac{3\pi}{2},-1\Big)$ on the function. The chord connecting them is below the function itself (since $f(\pi)=0>-1$ for example) and thus it can't be convex.